# Warum steht das Subjekt hier am Satzende?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Da ich muede bin, schlafe ich.

"Ich schlafe" ist hier der Hauptsatz, oder?

Warum steht dann das Subjekt, "ich", am Satzende?

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb steht im Hauptsatz immer an der zweiten Stelle:

> Ich **schlafe** auf dem Bett.
>
> Auf dem Bett **schlafe** ich.

Im Fall deiner Frage ist der komplette Nebensatz das erste Satzglied, weshalb das Verb auch in diesem Fall an zweiter Stelle steht. Dass das Subjekt am Satzende steht, ist reiner Zufall, da der Hauptsatz keine weiteren Informationen enthält. Würde man diesen erweitern, stünde das Subjekt nicht mehr am Ende:

> Da ich müde bin, schlafe ich noch weitere drei Stunden.

Comment: Leider ist das mit der ersten oder dritten Stelle nicht richtig, siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25266/can-the-subject-in-inverted-word-order-be-not-right-after-the-verb (englisch).

Comment: Danke, ich habe den Beitrag überarbeitet!